# JOOQ multi-field custom type converter

Tags: java, jooq

We have some custom types that reflected to multiple db fields. For example

```
PersonName{
  String salutation, 
  String firstName, 
  String lastName
}
```

stored as 3 separate db fields.
And it's boring to always write

```
db.select(PERSON.FIRST_NAME, PERSON.LAST_NAME, PERSON.SALUTATION, ... some other fields)
```

then fetch the record and create PersonName type from the appropriate record fields.

The idea is to define some multi-column custom field `PERSON_NAME`, which will be expanded by jooq into three "real" fields during the query execution, and packed to the one `PersonName` object in the result.

Looks like it's possible to do something like this with `org.jooq.impl.AbstractField`, but I'm wondering, may be there is a solution for such case already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are pending feature requests to support this kind of functionality:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2360 (nested records)
- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2530 (fetch groups)

With out-of-the-box functionality of jOOQ 3.6, you could store those columns somewhere as:

```
Field<?>[] personName = {
    PERSON.SALUTATION,
    PERSON.FIRST_NAME,
    PERSON.LAST_NAME
};
```

And then select them as such:

```
db.select(personName)
  .select(... some other fields);
```